# XmlDataSource binding doesn't display result in properly

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I've binded the `ComboBox` with Xml Datasource, I want to display the data is like Day, Month and Year one by one in the `ComboBox`. But now it displays DayMonthYear in `ComboBox`.

How can I acheive this?

```
<RecordSet>
    <Rows>
        <Row>Day</Row>
        <Row>Month</Row>
        <Row>Year</Row>
    </Rows>
</RecordSet>

 <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="MyDependCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ComboBox.DataContext>
            <XmlDataProvider Source="/Data/MyContentYearData.xml" XPath="/RecordSet/Rows"/>
        </ComboBox.DataContext>
</ComboBox>
```

The answers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XPath="/RecordSet/Rows/Row"`

...(28,29,30)

Comment: I'm little confused about this binding. can you please explain ?

Comment: You want to bind to each of the three 'Row' elements, rather than the single enclosing 'Rows' element